# Does google drive work with Finder integration?

Tags: macos, finder, google-apps

I know there is an app from google, but it is to automatically upload files from macos to drive. I would like to be able to see the files that are in my drive from the finder, open then and when saved have them be uploaded directly, so pretty much the same as google drive in a browser.

Is it possible to have access to my google drive documents directly from the finder?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Google [Backup & Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) app does exactly that.